# Emojicon use in android with webservice

Tags: android, web-services, unicode, utf-8, emoji

Hello friends I used [Emojicon Lib](https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon) in my project but when I send that to web service some of It emojicon work and another emojicon not work when I retrive from web. When I decode unicode of emojicon to string I found that some of that emojicon code is like \uxxxx and some are like \uxxxx\uxxxx. Second one are not working first one are working well. I used UTF-8 for url encoded type. anybody have any idea what should I have to change to make it working.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Hey did you find answer of this question?